# IOS 7, Code for customised UIPickerView

Tags: ios

I am looking for code to create customised UIPickerView.
Crate UIPickerView by code, set all its parameter and elements programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:myPickerView];
```

upto this write in your `viewDidLoad`,now implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Handle the selection
}

// tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSUInteger numRows = 5;

    return numRows;
}

// tell the picker how many components it will have
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
 return 1;
}

// tell the picker the title for a given component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *title;
    title = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",row];

    return title;
}

// tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 int sectionWidth = 300;

 return sectionWidth;
}
```